# Where to store environment variables when using AWS CDK Pipelines?

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-pipeline

I've followed [this tutorial](https://cdkworkshop.com/50-java/70-advanced-topics/100-pipelines.html) to set up CDK Pipelines using Python with a trigger from Github.

It looks something like this:

```py
import aws_cdk as cdk
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk.pipelines import CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep
from my_pipeline.my_pipeline_app_stage import MyPipelineAppStage

class MyPipelineStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        pipeline =  CodePipeline(self, "Pipeline",
                        pipeline_name="MyPipeline",
                        synth=ShellStep("Synth",
                            input=CodePipelineSource.git_hub("OWNER/REPO", "main"),
                            commands=[
                                "npm install -g aws-cdk",
                                "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt",
                                "cdk synth"]))

        pipeline.add_stage(MyPipelineAppStage(self, "my-stack"))
```

I want to be able to get custom environment variables from my CDK stack. For example:

```
organizational_unit_ids=[
  os.environ.get("OU_ID"),
]
```

I don't want to store these environment variables directly in my code. Now my question is, where should I store these environment variables in order for the `synth` `ShellStep` to use them?

Should I add them manually to the CodeBuild action after it has been created?

Or is there somewhere central I can store them?

Comment: You could store them in AWS parameter store, as one option

Comment: And then retrieve it from the Python code like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_ssm_value.html)? Or is there a way to pass it to the CodeBuild action using a buildspec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeBuild can retrieve your env var at run-time.

First, store your environment variable as a parameter in the Parameter Store (or in SecretsManager).

Then, set the parameter to a CodeBuild environment variable.  To do this, use the [CodeBuildStep](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeBuildStep.html) construct for the synth input, not `ShellStep`. The generic `ShellStep` construct, which supports multiple deployment platforms, can't set CodeBuild environment variables.  `CodeBuildStep` [can](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16145#issuecomment-902652993).

Set the environment variable in the [build_environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_codebuild/BuildEnvironment.html) arg.  The value will be retrieved at run-time. Add permissions for CodeBuild to read your parameter value by adding a policy statement to `role_policy_statements`.

```py
synth=CodeBuildStep(
    "Synth",
    input=CodePipelineSource.git_hub("OWNER/REPO", "main"),
    commands=[
        "npm install -g aws-cdk",
        "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt",
        "cdk synth",
    ],
    build_environment={
        "environment_variables": {
            "OU_ID": {
                "type": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PARAMETER_STORE,
                "value": "my-ou-param",
            }
        }
    },
    role_policy_statements=[
        iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=["ssm:GetParameter"],
            resources=[
                self.format_arn(
                    service="ssm",
                    resource="parameter",
                    resource_name="my-ou-param",
                    arn_format=cdk.ArnFormat.SLASH_RESOURCE_NAME,
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score -1):

When using AWS CDK pipeline, you can store ev in aws systems manager parameter store or aws secrets manager. These are storage for sensitive information.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.SsmClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.GetParameterRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.GetParameterResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.ParameterType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.PutParameterRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.PutParameterResponse;

public class ParameterStoreExample {
private static final String PARAMETER_NAME = "/myapp/paramName";
private static final String PARAMETER_VALUE = "mySecretValue";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SsmClient ssmClient = SsmClient.create();
    // Store parameter
    PutParameterRequest putParameterRequest = PutParameterRequest.builder()
            .name(PARAMETER_NAME)
            .value(PARAMETER_VALUE)
            .type(ParameterType.SECURE_STRING)
            .build();
    PutParameterResponse putParameterResponse = ssmClient.putParameter(putParameterRequest);

    // Retrieve parameter
    GetParameterRequest getParameterRequest = GetParameterRequest.builder()
            .name(PARAMETER_NAME)
            .withDecryption(true)
            .build();
    GetParameterResponse getParameterResponse = ssmClient.getParameter(getParameterRequest);
    String retrievedValue = getParameterResponse.parameter().value();
    System.out.println("Retrieved value: " + retrievedValue);
}
```

Comment: The question was asking about Python, not Java

Comment: I'd be okay with solutions in other languages, but not with storing my secrets in clear text in my code.